# c++11 enable_if error - template parameter re-declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, enable-if

I am trying to get the following code to compile:

```
template <class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int >::type = 0 >
class Calc
{
  public:
    int operator()( const T& v ) const {
        return v.getValue();
    }
};

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int >::type = 0 >
class Calc : CalcBase <T>
{
};
```

On compilation I am getting the following error:

```
c.cpp:26: error: template parameter 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_fundamental::value), int>::type <anonymous>'
c.cpp:36: error: redeclared here as 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental::value, int>::type <anonymous>'
```

The intent here is to select the the version of Calc that overrides the base class function call operator if the passed template parameter is a class. If the passed parameter is a fundamental type, then we choose the version of Calc that does not override the base class functionality.
Could you please help me understand how I can get this working?

Comment: You need to show more of your code. It's not clear what is supposed to be the primary template, what is / are the specialization(s)

Comment: Also it's not clear what this is supposed to mean: `typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, int >::type = 0` When and why would a type be equal to zero? Normally I would think the answer is, never.

Comment: @ChrisBeck In his case, `type` is an alias for `int`, and `int` can be a non-type template parameter which can have a default value (such as 0). That is actually one way to remove a function from participating in overload resolution because when the condition of `std::enable_if<>` is false, there is no `type` alias and SFINAE takes place.

Comment: I see, I never saw that one before. It's more common to see `typename ENABLE = typename std::enable_if<...>::type`

Comment: @ChrisBeck and @ user2296177. Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. Dietmar Kühl has provided a solution which has solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think class template declarations work with SFINAE: a class template isn't overloaded like a function template. You are declaring two primary class templates with the same name which isn't allowed.

Conveniently, SFINAE isn't necessary for your use-case: class templates support partial specialization. You'd simply use a defaulted `bool` parameter and specialize the class template on whether the trait is `true` or `false`. For example:

```
template <class T, bool = std::is_fundamental<T>::value>
class Calc
{
  public:
    int operator()( const T& v ) const {
        return v.getValue();
    }
};

template <class T>
class Calc<T, false> : CalcBase <T>
{
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. And indeed a very elegant solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use SFINAE with class templates is via partial specializations that specialize a template parameter using SFINAE.

Here is a minimum working example that implements the classes described in the question.

In an instantiation of `Calc`, the template parameter `U` either has the default type of `void` or has the type `void` but via an `enable_if` condition being `true` or be involved an SFINAE type error if an `enable_if` condition is `false`.

Because of `U` having the default argument of `void`, a type `T` that results in SFINAE type error for all the partial specializations would still lead to an instantiation of the class template based on the default argument and avoid a compile time error. Note: in this particular case, one of the conditions must be `true` but having a default argument would help in other situations.

```
#include <type_traits>

class NonFundamental {
public:
  NonFundamental(int val) : val_(val) {}

  int getValue() {
    return val_;
  }

private:
  int val_;
};

template <typename T>
class Calcbase {};

template <typename T, typename U = void>
class Calc {};

template <typename T>
class Calc<T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental_v<T>>> {
public:
  int operator()(const T &v) const {
    return v.getValue();
  }
};

template <typename T> 
class Calc<T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>> : Calcbase<T> {
};

int main() {
  Calc<int> calc_obj_1;
  Calc<NonFundamental> calc_obj_2;

  return 0;
}
```